# Does vue.config.js work when the project is created using webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

My project was created using `webpack`, not `Vue-cli`, and I tried to modify `vue.config.js` to configure the `proxy`, as shown below, but it doesn't take effect.

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/public'),
  devServer:{
    proxy: 'http://localhost:8081'
  }
}
```

I guess when a project is created using webpack, I can not configure `vue.config.js`, is that correct?
If it is, how to configure the `proxy`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use webpack.config.js` and modify [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy).

Comment: I have changed it to `webpack.config.js`, but it doesn't work either. I posted another question, could you please also help me with that? Thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560647/why-webpack-config-js-doesnt-work-in-my-vue-project?noredirect=1#comment108894065_61560647